# Use of wild card character in escape()

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

There is a column named 'ename' in emp table if I entered r__oshan as the value of that column to emp and then I perform escape() as " select* from table name where columnname like ' %?______' escape'?' ;" then I got 'r__oshan'  as output. Can anyone help me to understand how and why I got this type of output ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? See line #8.

```
SQL> with emp (ename) as
  2    (select 'Little_Foot' from dual union all
  3     select 'r__oshan'    from dual union all
  4     select 'r_oshan'     from dual union all
  5     select 'roshan'      from dual
  6    )
  7  select * from emp
  8  where regexp_like(ename, '(\_)+');

ENAME
-----------
Little_Foot
r__oshan
r_oshan

SQL>
```

On a second thought, it can be even simpler:

```
where regexp_like(ename, '_+');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking why `like '%?______' escape '?'` matches `r__oshan`.

Only the first `_` character is escaped, so your pattern matches anything followed by a literal underscore `_`, followed by any five characters. `r__oshan` matches that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for an explanation rather than "How do I do this?" If that is the case, the `escape` key word uses the following character as an escape character.  In your example, that means that the ? "escapes" the following character from being treated as a special character.  In a `like` statement, the `_` character means any single character.

For instance, `where 'x' like '_'` would be true and `where 'xx' like '_'` would be false.  When you escape the special character (`_` in this case), it is just treated literally.  So now, you are actually looking for the `_` character.

Here is an example with the escape:

```sql
where 'x' like '?_' escape '?' /** Evaluates false **/
where '_' like '?_' escape '?' /** Evaluates True **/
```